# Detecting Nvidia Graphics card on Ubuntu running on a VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware, nvidia, video-card

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on VmWare 9. When I tried to install the Nvidia drivers, its unable to detect the hardware (GEForce GT 540M). Is there a workaround?

OS: Windows 8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VMware VMs don't use native Nvidia or ATI drivers.  They basically have a VMware driver that supports accelerated 3D. This accelerated 3D uses the native driver on your host machine to improve 3D performance, for example play games, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so does that mean I can't install cuda on my VM Ubuntu?

Comment: No you can't. Check this thread too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2260931/cuda-program-on-vmware